# React onClick bind(), where is the click event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an element with `onClick={this.didSelectReview.bind(this,review)}`.

In the `didSelectReview`-function I would like to stop the click event by calling. `e.stopPropagation()`. But how can I get the click event `e`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `.bind()` does is that it prepends default arguments in the call. So you will have the original arguments right there in your function:

```
this.didSelectReview = function(review,clickevent){
    clickevent.stopPropagation();

}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind